# Java-messages to client from server after client reconnects to server

Tags: java, sockets, messaging

I would like to know if there is any way to get messages from one client to another client and if receiving client is not connected to a server, but connects after some time, that client should receive those messages.

Suppose client A and Client B:

1. Client A sends messages to client B, but client B is offline
2. Client A message must be stored on server in some sort(that I'd like
   to know)
3. When Client B connects to a server should receive all the messages for it which were sent to this client when it was offline.

Everything should be done in Java using sockets.

Is there any mechanism to store those offline messages and then send them to a client as soon as it connects to a server?

Comment: This sounds like a job for JMS.

Comment: But how to use JMS in Java socket programming

Answer (score 0):

You can use different types of storage - database, in memory, some cloud storage, plain text files or whatever.  So for example if you store all messages in memory (to make it simpler) and you have an incrementing ID for each message and a sender and receiver (I guess you can do it in different way but I am just giving a suggestion).

So when a new client connect to the server and authenticate (to make sure if  Client B joins the chat it is the same Client B as before) the client can "tell" the server the last message ID received. And then the server can push the missed message to the client. Of course it depends a lot on your model and what exactly do you want to achieve. Probably in memory storage for message won't be the best you can use a database or something else - depending on your needs.